# Argument of type 'HTMLDivElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLImageElement'

Tags: angular, typescript

Below mentioned code is working in another project and when i am trying to clone same project codr then i am getting above error.

```
<div
  *ngIf="option['opt_image']"
  class="
    mt-2
    test-img-container
    d-flex
    align-items-start
    justify-content-between
  "
>
  <div #optionImage>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="close-button d-none btn btn-link text-black"
      (click)="enlargeImage(optionImage)"
    >
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>
    <img
      class="img-responsive"
      [src]="option['opt_image']"
      alt="Option Image"
    />
  </div>
  <button
    class="p-2 btn btn-link text-black"
    type="button"
    (click)="enlargeImage(optionImage)"
  >
    <i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

ts

```
enlargeImage(imgRef: HTMLImageElement) {
    if (imgRef.classList.contains('enlarge-image')) {
      this.renderer.removeClass(imgRef, 'enlarge-image');
    } else {
      this.renderer.addClass(imgRef, 'enlarge-image');
    }
}
```

when i am trying above code i am getting above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

Since you are placing the reference on a div you are getting the type for the DIV, replacing that solves the issue and the functionality is working fine!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="option['opt_image']"
        class="mt-2 test-img-container d-flex align-items-start justify-content-between">
        <div #optionImage>
            <button type="button" class="close-button d-none btn btn-link text-black"
                (click)="enlargeImage(optionImage)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            <img class="img-responsive" [src]="option['opt_image']" alt="Option Image">
        </div>
        <button class="p-2 btn btn-link text-black" type="button"
            (click)="enlargeImage(optionImage)"><i class="fa fa-expand"
                aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  option = {
    opt_image: 'https://placehold.co/600x400',
  };

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  enlargeImage(imgRef: HTMLDivElement) {
    if (imgRef.classList.contains('enlarge-image')) {
      this.renderer.removeClass(imgRef, 'enlarge-image');
    } else {
      this.renderer.addClass(imgRef, 'enlarge-image');
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-a6wmpa)